# Get TextView in the parent of prent of Button

Tags: android, textview, android-textattributes

I have a layout for **a** row of `LIstView` items like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="40sp" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"  />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_btn"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="share"
            android:onClick="myClickHandler" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And i want to get the text of `TextView` when user click on delete button(in myClickHandler() method),

with this code:

```
RelativeLayout vwParentRow = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
```

I get the parent of `Button`(RelativeLayout), but don't know how to get the text of `TextView` that in parent of parent of `Button`

How i can to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for you:

In your **myClickHandler-method** you can use the following code to determine what the content of your textview was:

```
public void myClickHandler(View v) {
    ViewParent relativeLayout = v.getParent();
    ViewParent linearLayout = relativeLayout.getParent();

    TextView textView = (TextView) ((View) linearLayout).findViewById(R.id.label);
    String text = textView.getText().toString();
    Log.i("textview content", text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> And i want to get the text of TextView when user click on delete button(in myClickHandler() method),

To get the text of the textView, use:

```
String text = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.label)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: sorry,i forget to say this layout is for ListView items

Comment: What exactly want you to happen, when the user clicks on your button?

Comment: Exactly i want to share text of TextView

Comment: see my other answer @odr_m9611

Answer (score 1):

What about in your button's `onClick` trying the following:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.label);
String text = myTextView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: sorry,i forget to say this layout is for ListView items